# Using R how to create histogram with relative frequency on the vertical axis?

Tags: r, histogram

I want to create a histogram with relative frequency on the vertical axis using R.

```
Data:
Size: [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
Observations:[2, 8, 23, 1]
```

I would like the size as breaks on the x axis and the relative frequency on y.

```
obs = c(2, 8, 23, 1)
Y_data = obs/sum(obs)*100
```

Edit:

```
hist(Y_data, breaks=seq(1.0, 2.5, 0.5), freq = FALSE)
```

Getting Error: some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'

Comment: `hist(..., freq = FALSE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems not a good method for plotting histogram

```
Size <- c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5)
obs <- c(2, 8, 23, 1)
Y_data <- obs/sum(obs)*100
t1 <- hist(Size, plot=FALSE)
t1$breaks <- c(0,Size)
t1$counts <- Y_data
plot(t1, xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(0,100), freq=TRUE)
```

Maybe you should figure out a way that makes hist function do the calculation and plot for you.